# Barcodes in Crystal reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, barcode, crystal-reports-2008, barcode-printing

I'm not able to print barcodes in `Crystal` Report...
I have to print this barcode

[image]

In my `crystal` Report I have this formula binded with the `field`

```
BarcodeEAN13({@x},"")
```

and the @x is

```
{TabA.cod_ean13}
```

that is a `varchar` field in my DB, table TabA

Now, my c# method sets the `datasource` to the crystal report and export in `PDF`.
The code is the following:

```
string root_path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Percorso_RPT"];
            string spath = Utility.PathCombine(root_path, cod_etic + "D.rpt");

            ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
            cryRpt.Load(spath);

            List<DatiStampa> lista = new List<DatiStampa>();
            lista.Add(ds);

            cryRpt.SetDataSource(Utility.DataTableFromIEnumerable(lista));

            //export in pdf     
            cryRpt.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, path);
            cryRpt.Close();
            cryRpt.Dispose();
```

Here is what I obtain in the `barcode field`

[image]

I already tried to change the font, but nothing to do...

I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you embedding the barcode font in the pdf?

Comment: No, to generate the pdf I do only cryRpt.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, path);

Comment: What happens when you change the barcode font to something human readable?

Comment: @BrianAnderson it prints this string: Ê|xAKJLTHy111119z

Answer (score 0):

Already had a similar problem in another framework.  It turned out that the font was too big and the textbox too small.  After that a small part was missing and the barcode could not be read correctly.

Comment: even if I try do put the font size smaller, the barcode is not right :(

Answer (score 0):

EAN-13 Barcodes are named that way, not because they support 13 digits, but because there are 12 digits worth of data and 1 checksum character. Regardless of what the text under the first example barcode above says, the data returned by a scanner is '8009197111119'. Which makes sense because the checksum for '800919711111' is '9'.

The '80' indicates the EAN13 code is assigned to an Italian company whose company code is probably '09197'. The next five characters '11111' are the product code.

EAN barcodes are similar to what people in the US refer to as UPC symbols and they are very difficult to implement as a font. The symbol segment for the numbers in the first half of the entire symbol are black and white reversed from the characters in the second half. That's why whatever software is generating the character codes for producing the barcodes appears to be using 'letters' for the first half and the correct last 6 digits in numbers for the second half.

That, combined with a rather complicated algorithm required for generating the final checksum digit make EAN-13 barcodes impossible to generate without some code to manipulate any font you use. The second image you've attached above does not resemble an EAN font and looks more like Code39. The font is incorrectly sized and is being cropped, regardless.

I am not well versed in c#, so I made a little utility that may help test your code in JavaScript.

```js
// The MIT License (MIT)

// Copyright (c) 2018, Notionovus, LLC.

// Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
// of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
// in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
// to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
// copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
// furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

// The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
// all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
// IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
// FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
// AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
// LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
// FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER
// DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

// Generic arrays for drawing 5-bit graphics. Building blocks for all barcode symbologies
// Painstakingly derived gobblety-goop, but essentially the two middle sections of image data unique to each graphic
var array5bit_A = new Array ( 'f//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', 'f//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB', 'f//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAD/',
 'f//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAA', 'f//AAAAAAAAAQAAAP8AAAAA', 'f//AAAAAAAAAQAAAP8AAAAB', 'f//AAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAD/',
 'f//AAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAA', 'f//AAABAAAA/wAAAAAAAAAA', 'f//AAABAAAA/wAAAAAAAAAB', 'f//AAABAAAA/wAAAAEAAAD/',
 'f//AAABAAAA/wAAAAEAAAAA', 'f//AAABAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAA', 'f//AAABAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAB', 'f//AAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/',
 'f//AAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAEAAAD/',
 'QD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAEAAAAA', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAP8AAAAA', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAP8AAAAB', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAAAAAAD/',
 'QD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAAAAAAAA', 'QD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAAAAAAA', 'QD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAAAAAAB', 'SL/AADeAAAA/gAAAAIAAAD+',
 'QD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAEAAAAA', 'QD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAA', 'QD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAB', 'QD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/',
 'QD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA');
var array5bit_B = new Array ( 'US0CAuSD38g', 'UUYCA7QBErs', 'ajEDAm49ReY', 'UUoCA+juogg', 'bjEDAjQrOn0', 'bkoDA3iPVH4',
 'ajUDAt82atY', 'UU4CA1nljTg', 'cjEDAghkmFU', 'ckoDA0TA9lY', 'izUEAhrxcbg', 'ck4DAxY8F10', 'bjUDAlvFFR8', 'bk4DAxdhexw',
 'ajkDAr7LFAw', 'UVICAyQ+UJI', 'TTECAq7UnEM', 'TUoCA+Jw8kA', 'ZjUDAmZGozo', 'TU4CA7CME0s', 'ajUDAvnk9E4', 'ak4DA7VAmk0',
 'ZjkDAtle3bI', 'TVICAxOyzrM', 'STUCAqHeHtM', 'SU4CA+16cNA', 'h6QEAZKdo54', 'SVICA62zYxM', 'RTkCAqx1lb4', 'RVICA/z3WM0',
 'QT0CAkdoxRU', 'KFYBA46vJCA');

// Painstakingly derived gobblety-goop, but essentially the front, back and mid-matter common to all barcode images...
var stringStart = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/A';
var stringMid = 'AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';
var stringEnd = 'AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="';

function genBarcode(inputString,intWidth,intHeight) { // Input is a long string of 1's and 0's, output is the HTML <img> stack
// Pads to the last character to ensure length is divisible by 5
   var intRawmod = inputString.length % 5; // Modulo 5 remainder
   if (intRawmod > 0) for (var i = 0; i < 5 - intRawmod; i++) inputString += "0"; // If not evenly divisible, pad with zeroes
   var arraySeq = new Array (intChunks = inputString.length / 5); // Create array for as many chunks as are now in input string

   for (var i = 0; i < intChunks; i++) arraySeq[i] = parseInt(inputString.substr(i * 5, 5), 2); // Converts string of 1's and 0's to integer array

// Takes integer array and converts to "<img ...>" graphics for display
   var resultString = "";
   for (var i = 0; i < arraySeq.length; i++) {
    resultString += stringStart + array5bit_A[arraySeq[i]] + stringMid + array5bit_B[arraySeq[i]] + stringEnd + intWidth + '" height="' + intHeight + '">';
   }
   return resultString;
}
///////////////////////////////////////////
// Symbology-specific arrays

// UPC Specific Arrays
var arrayCodeEANBin, arrayStructEAN;
arrayCodeEANBin = [ [ '0001101', '0011001', '0010011', '0111101', '0100011', '0110001', '0101111', '0111011', '0110111', '0001011' ], [ '0100111', '0110011', '0011011', '0100001', '0011101', '0111001', '0000101', '0010001', '0001001', '0010111' ], [ '1110010', '1100110', '1101100', '1000010', '1011100', '1001110', '1010000', '1000100', '1001000', '1110100' ] ];
arrayStructEAN = ['000000', '001011', '001101', '001110', '010011', '011001', '011100', '010101', '010110', '011010'];

///////////////////////////////////////////
// Global Variables
var strRaw = "";
var strText = "";

///////////////////////////////////////////
// Symbology-specific functions
function funcEAN() { // EAN-13
var intSumOdd = 0, intSumEven = 0, intCheck, i, j, strStruct;

// Compute check digit and add it to raw string
 for (i = 0; i < 12; i += 2) {
  intSumEven += parseInt(strText[i]);
  intSumOdd += parseInt(strText[i+1]);
 }
 intCheck = ((intSumOdd * 3) + intSumEven) % 10;
 if (intCheck > 0) {
  intCheck = 10 - intCheck;
 }
 strText += intCheck;

// Converts Code EAN array into string of 1's and 0's
 strRaw = "101";
// First six bar sequences
 strStruct = arrayStructEAN[strText[0]];
 for (i = 1; i < 7; i += 1) {
   strRaw += arrayCodeEANBin[strStruct[i-1]][strText[i]];
 }
// Middle sequence
 strRaw += "01010";
// Last six bar sequences, including check digit
 for (i = 0; i < 6; i += 1) {
  strRaw += arrayCodeEANBin[2][strText[i+7]];
 }
 strRaw += "101";
} // End EAN-13


var buttonBarcode = document.getElementById("btnGenBar");
buttonBarcode.onclick = function () {
 var intHt = intWd = 0;
 var strImages = "";
 document.getElementById("textImages").value = strImages;
 intWd = document.getElementById("textWidth").value;
 intHt = document.getElementById("textHeight").value;
 strText = document.getElementById("textBarcode").value;
 funcEAN();
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = strImages = genBarcode(strRaw,intWd,intHt);
 document.getElementById("textImages").value = strImages;
 document.getElementById("textRaw").value = strRaw;
 document.getElementById("textImages").select();
}
```

```html
<head>
<title>EAN-13 Barcodes in vanilla JavaScript</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
</head>
<body>
  <h1>EAN-13 Barcodes written in vanilla JavaScript</h1>
  <h4>Enter text (a 12-digit number), enter a non-ridiculous height in pixels, enter a width between 4 (so small) and 40 (gigantor) and press the button. Magic will ensue. Print page or copy HTML out of box and paste it where it will do some good.</h4>  
 <div id="inputForm">
  Enter Text:&nbsp;<input type="text" id="textBarcode" placeholder="12 Digit Number" tabindex=1/>
  &nbsp;Height:&nbsp;<input type="text" id="textHeight" size="3" placeholder="40-100" maxlength="5" tabindex=2/>
  &nbsp;Width:&nbsp;<input type="text" id="textWidth" size="3" placeholder="4.0-40.9" maxlength="5" tabindex=3/>
  &nbsp;
  <input type="button" id="btnGenBar" value="Generate Barcode" tabindex=4/>
 </div>
 <p></p>
 <div id="result"></div>
 <p></p>
 <textarea rows="30" cols="110" id="textImages" tabindex=0></textarea>
 <p></p>
 <textarea rows="3" cols="110" id="textRaw" tabindex=0></textarea>
</body>
```